# How to set the user.home directory used by Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, location, home-directory

When Eclipse starts, it generates folders such as the workspace and the .eclipse folder which is found in the user folder in Windows environments. 
While the location of the first one is easy to set (Eclipse asks you about the workspace location), I've got a lot of troubles setting the location I want for the .eclipse folder.

In fact, the problem comes from the fact that I have 2 different hard drives : C:/ and D:/. 
I would like Eclipse to create his .eclipse folder in C:/Users/username. Instead, it creates it in D:/Users/username.

I don't find any way to force the location of the .eclipse folder. Adding "osgi.configuration.area=C:/Users/username\" in the eclipse.ini proved relevant partially : the eclipse configuration part of the .eclipse folder is located where I want, but other folders found in the .eclipse aren't moved, therefore Eclipse still creates a .eclipse in D:/.

I simply would like to find a correct line of code to put in the eclipse.ini (for example) in order to have Eclipse creating the files he automatically creates in C:/Users/username instead of D:/Users/username.